# Removing an Array of words from Another array or word in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have an array of stop words that i would like removed from a string.  But in every case the words like 'in' are being removed from valid words like climbing leaving climb g in the resulting string.

I was thinking if I could have two arrays. One array of the stop words and one array of the exploded string.
Is there a quick way to use the array of stop words to compare against the array of the exploded string, thus removing all stop words from the exploded string array...

```
$stopwords = array( 'foo', 'bar');
$string = "foo bar Foobar";
$newArray = explode(" ", $string)
```

I would like the resulting $string = "Foobar"?

thanks in advance,

Marv

Comment: is this a poor attempt to censor swear words?

Comment: nope... doing a student project on clustering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff) is your friend to eliminate the words you don't like too see:

```
$string = implode(" ", array_diff(explode(" ", $string), $stopwords));
```

Comment: @user2620610 then please mark the green bordered tick on the left under my answer's score to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), it will return you the difference between first and second array. For conversion to string, you must make sure you have only 1 last element (with *count*, for instance)